# Unable to fetch data while applying condition on date-time format in R studio

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, syntax-error, logical-operators

I am a beginner in R programming. I am trying to fetch the data with the time. I have used

```
 select(hrsr, mid, sr) %>% arrange(sr) %>% filter(Hours > "01:00" & Hours < "03:00")
```

to get the data/rows in-between this timestamp from the table below:

```
mid            hr                     sr     t     s Hours
   <chr>          <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
 1 countrydelight 2020-02-12 00:00:00  75      36    27 00:00
 2 countrydelight 2020-02-12 01:00:00  79.8   104    83 01:00
 3 countrydelight 2020-02-12 02:00:00  78.6   131   103 02:00
 4 countrydelight 2020-02-12 03:00:00  78.7   136   107 03:00
 5 countrydelight 2020-02-12 04:00:00  79.4   160   127 04:00
 6 countrydelight 2020-02-12 05:00:00  76.8   263   202 05:00
 7 countrydelight 2020-02-12 06:00:00  76.3   278   212 06:00
```

Getting below error:

```
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 70 or 1, not size 573.
ℹ Input `..1` is `Hours > "01:00" & Hours < "03:00"`.
ℹ The error occured in group 1: mid = "countrydelight".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are two main issues here. First, you select the columns 'mid' and 'sr' from the dataset 'hrsr' but try to filter on the column 'Hours'. Second, 'Hours' is a character column, so using '<' and '>' wont work.

Try to use this code, probably that solves it:

```
hrsr %>%
  filter(lubridate::hour(hr) > 1 % lubridate::hour(hr) < 3) %>%
  arrange(sr) %>%
  select(mid, sr)
```